# Empty JSON returned by AFNetworking on iOS5

Tags: iphone, json, ios5, afnetworking

I'm trying to load a simple JSON inside my iPhone app using the AFNetworking library. I'm using two different approaches:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.mysite.com/test.json"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {

    NSLog(@"Name: %@", [JSON valueForKeyPath:@"name"]);
} failure:^(NSURLRequest* req,NSHTTPURLResponse *req2, NSError *error,id mex) {
    NSLog(@"%@", [error description]);
}];

[operation start];
```

and using AFHttpClient (which would be my favorite,since it has all the features for dealing with my REST API:

```
    NSString *baseurl = @"http://www.mysite.com";

NSString *path = @"/test.json";

AFHTTPClient *client = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:baseurl]];
[client registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFJSONRequestOperation class]];
//[client setAuthorizationHeaderWithUsername:@"myusername" password:@"mypassword"];

[client getPath:path parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id JSON) {

    //NSLog(@"sjson: %@", [JSON valueForKeyPath:@"entries"]);
    NSLog(@"sjson: %@", JSON);        
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error Code: %i - %@",[error code], [error localizedDescription]);
}];
```

now,the problem: in both cases I'm receiving an empty Json. I've tested the server side and the web-service is giving the right response and the right MIME type (application/json).

I've already checked this discussion https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/175
but my target is pointing to 5.0 and ARC is not enabled for the AFNetworking library.

Maybe I'm missing something obvious here,but I cannot fix it at the moment.

Thanks a lot!

Claus

Comment: I think I found the solution. It was pretty trivial but the implications maybe not so much.
I was using an invalid JSON:

{
    name: "simon",
    surname: "test"
}

At the first moment I was thinking it was correct since I was using an online JSON viewer which I think was also validating the content. ..Well,it wasn't...so I was giving for granted the input coming from my local server was correct. Simple,lethal...  The worst bugs are usually wrong assumptions :)

Comment: However this error leads to another interesting implication: even if the JSON returned was invalid AFNetworking was calling the success: block with a Null answer and not the fail: block

I'm wondering if this is the intended behaviour.

Comment: The success or failure of this, then, is totally on your JSON library. If there was an error parsing, it would be up to the JSON library to communicate that. `AFJSONDecode` supports error reference arguments; if something went wrong and `**error` was set, that _would_ cause `AFJSONRequestOperation` to fail.